# Thread variable issue

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I expect the variable in the loop to output 1,2,3 to my listbox below. But it outputs
2
2
2

what is wrong?

**C# Code**

```
  public partial class Tester : Form
    {

public int test = 1;


............................

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test++;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);                 


                }).ContinueWith(o =>
                {


                    listBox1.Items.Add(test);


                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            }

        }
```

Comment: 'test++;' is executed once per button click. After it has been increased to 2, you enter your loop. This means the value will be 2 for all the threads.

Comment: Simon has the explanation for the current behavior. But it's likely once you move the "test++" into the loop, you'll run into the classic "captured wrong variable instance" problem. So be sure to read the reference provided by thumbmunkeys.

Comment: And of course, if you move it into the cycle (note that you have to declare the variable there as well - just copy the incremented value from the field, otherwise you'll get `4 4 4` instead :D), there's no guarantee you'll get `1 2 3` - you might get `2 1 3` instead, for example. If that's what you want, fine. If not, you might want to move the increment to the continuation - this will ensure you'll always get `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the sequence in which the Tasks are done you can use the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int tasknumber = test;
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return tasknumber;

        }).ContinueWith(o =>
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(o.Result);
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        test++;
    }
}
```

With this code, the value of `test` is increased at the end of every loop. In the first Task, the tasknumber will be 1. In the second Task the tasknumber will be 2 etc. When the Task is done, the result will be passed to your ListBox.

You might also want to read [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) about StartNew.